# Drawable[] from ArrayList with for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is it possible to generate a `Drawable[]` with a for loop?

ArrayList:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App/posters/80348-16.jpg");
list.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App/posters/83462-8.jpg");
```

to

```
   private Drawable[] mThumbIds = {
        Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Treevo/posters/80348-16.jpg"), Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Treevo/posters/83462-8.jpg")
};
```

My idea:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{

      //But what I need to do here?

}
```

My goal is to generate the Items for a `GridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure what kind of path it expects, but you could try [Drawable.createFromPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29) method. Assuming you store in the first list the right paths, you're loop would look like this.-

```
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[list.size()]();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    drawables[i] = Drawable.createFromPath(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Yes, it work but i want generate it automatically
private Drawable[] mThumbIds = {
            Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App/posters/80348-16.jpg"), Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App/posters/83462-8.jpg")
    };

Comment: Mmh not sure what you mean. What about declaring `Drawable[] drawables  = new Drawable[list.size()]();`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
list.add(new File(dir, "App/posters/80348-16.jpg"));
list.add(new File(dir, "App/posters/83462-8.jpg"));

List<Drawable> mThumbs = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
for (File file : list) {
    mThumbs.add(Drawable.createFromPath(file.getPath());
}
```

If you want to retrieve a list of all .jpg files in the folder, you can construct `list` like this:

```
File posterDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "App/posters");
List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
for (File file : posterDir.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
        list.add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but i should recommend to loop though posters folder and find all files with suffix that indicates picture.

Comment: @H.Moody - I had the impression that OP was not asking about constructing the list of files to be loaded, but how to process the list once available. There's nothing to suggest that OP wants to load all the pictures in the folder, but if that's what OP wants, your suggestion is a good one. I added code to show how it could be done.

Comment: No problem Mr. Ted Hopp it's just a note.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a for each loop. It goes something like this.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] imgPathList = ... // Add all of the "/App/poster..." strings here

for(String x : imgPathList) {
  list.add(Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + x);
}
```

Here is an example with different things.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] data = {
    "123",
    "456",
    "789"
};

for(String x : data) {
    list.add("Number: " + x);
}

System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Prints: "[Number: 123, Number: 456, Number: 789]"